# Is it possible to replicate adaptive subdivision in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, subdivision-surface

I want to replicate the Adaptive Subdivision inside geometry nodes in order to save memory while rendering. Now I know that I can just enable adaptive subdivision while rendering, but 2 things stop me from doing so.

1. I want to use Eevee for this project.
2. Adaptive subdivision will give me more geometry near the camera, but the one that is far away will be kinda wasted. Like even though it's not needed, it's still subdivided and in a few cases, it's actually not even necessary. I know how the dicing works, but there's still some kind of wastage.

I work on a potato. So saving memory has a huge importance to me.

Now, I did kinda solve this issue, but not completely. I basically used a proximity node along with a merge by distance node and a compare node. So any geometry which is far away from the camera will just merge. Repeating a bunch of these, I get a similar behavior as that of adaptive subdivision.

Now this has 2 problems:

1. The topology is a total mess. Even though that is no a concern for this case I (or someone else reading this post) might be able to use it in some future scenario. But, as I said, not a concern right now, and will just be helpful.
2. Say, the object is a plane, and my camera is slowyly rotating and going from facing forward to facing downward. Then in such a case, as the camera look more and more downwards, there will be wastage. I want a system that respect the way the camera is looking at the object. (If you know how fresnel works, you might be able to understand this 2nd point)

I don't have much memory to work with so I want to have minimum wastage. My potato can only handle about 2 Million vertices in the viewport. But while rendering, the maximum I have done to this day is about 500K.

Btw, the current setup:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: "_Adaptive subdivision will give me more geometry near the camera, but the one that is far away will be kinda wasted._" I do not understand what you mean with this... do you want to delete the geometry far away from the camera in order not to waste it?

Comment: The goal was to use lesser subdivision, so less geometry, But that's not exactly controlable. Also I don't want to completely delete it. I just want less of it as it goes far away. I cannot exactly control the fallout regarding how less the subdivions are as they go away fro the camera.

Comment: Hi, @Akshay2005. You should provide full context. That would increase your chances of getting meaningful answers. Why do you need this? Why can't you use subdivision modifier in adaptive mode?

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Because he wants to use _Eevee_ as he says under 1.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann, Oh, OK, makes sense, I did not know adaptive subdivision does not work in EEVEE.

Comment: @Akshay2005 I just did not understand what you were trying to say with 2., because as you say on 1., you want to use _Eevee_ and there is no _Adaptive Subdivision_. However, if there was in _Eevee_, there would be no wasted geometry because that's what the "adaptive" means - less resolution further away from the camera, which is what you want as you said.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Sorry, I mean't it with the currently available system.(I'll update the question) Like even though it's not needed, it's still subdivided. Like in a few cases, it's actually not even necessary. I know how the dicing works, but there's still some kind of wastage.

Comment: It's possible to use Decimate modifier with vertex groups and vertex goup weigths can be 0-1 and it decimates in a gradient, so one could probably use geometry nodes to make those weights for a vertex group based on camera position and then decimate modifier could use that. That would give slightly cleaner topology and maintain boundaries better, but is still inefficient with memory.

Comment: Actually it does not really matter how good or bad _Adaptive Subdivision_ works since you want to use _Eevee_ and not _Cycles_. So why not simply say you want something "like Adaptive Subdivision"? Since it will not be the same and work completely different in _Geometry Nodes_, why bother distracting from the main problem by pointing out that detail from the original _Adaptive Subdivision_?

Comment: Anyway, Cartesian Caramel made a video about recursive subdivision in _Geometry Nodes_ based on the distance to a target object's mesh. Maybe you can find something helpful there or draw some inspiration from it: [Dynamic Recursive Subdivision in Blender 3.6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8054D19fnJ0)

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys If I am correct, once all the modifiers are processes, only after that, the mesh get loaded onto the GPU right? As far as I understand, the modifiers are processed with the CPU, which doesn't have too many issues with memory. So if I am able to load less geometry on to the GPU in the first place. it should have no memorie issues right?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thanks and sorry. Will make sure to not mess up questions next time.

Comment: @Akshay2005, I haven't tested it, but I think so. I think it may help with fitting everything to VRAM. But subdividing will still need to happen on every frame and it is expensive for CPU and RAM. I cannot think of a way to subdivide adaptively with GN. I think the video mentioned just separates geometry and does not join it later, so it may be a problem for displacement that I suspect is the point of this, right?

Answer (score 0):

you could use a delete geometry node with a set of math to get a camera cull effect. it will delete everything outside of the POV.[image]

Comment: And this approach works for meshes that weren't created through Geometry Nodes as well; that is, for all geometry in the scene?

Comment: It does. You just have to create a geometry node for the mesh. So essentially the geometry node will take any mesh and change it based on you node sets. Doing this will work on any mesh.

Comment: Add about 15 to the 2nd to last node to give you some padding and allow it to extend behind your character. The only thing is you will have to create a 2 frame action. First frame showing all and the 2nd showing culling, and add in the action on init. This will generate all of the physics before culling. Basically without this the ground will only have physics for the culling spits and won't generate for the culled out.